# Adding a gatling test to a Spring Boot gradle project on IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gatling

I have a Spring Boot 2 application written in Kotlin (could be Java). The project uses gradle (not maven). The application exposes HTTP endpoints that I want to load test using gatling.

I created a *MySimulation.scala* file under *src/test/gatling*. IntelliJ suggested and I accepted the intallation of the Scala IntelliJ plugin. So, I got syntax highliting on the scala editor. :^)

I'd like to have code assist (drill down, code completion) for the scala gatling tests. 
What other tools/plugins/configuration do I need to add?

(I have the gatling bundle already installed on my computer. IntelliJ version is 2018.2.4.)

Comment: Have you added gatling dependency in your build script? According to this article (https://gist.github.com/groovybayo/4691670) nothing else is needed.

Comment: @y.bedrov I have not. I'd seen that article. It asks for creating a new project for the gatling test (I'd like to keep the simulation in my application project), and it  uses a maven configuration (I'd like to stick with gradle).  In any case, I could try adding a testCompile dependency to my `build.gradle`. But that article only mentions a maven archetype dependency.